# function uses this.state and pass it to another component

Tags: reactjs

hey guys simple question. i have a class component, with a state with two colors inside.
i want to create a onClick function, that when you click it, it shows 2 divs with backgroundColors from this.state.
and the button MOST be on the parent
here the code

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);

this.state = {
color1: "#38306b",
color2: "#fff285"
}

saveColors() = {
// thats the part i dont get.

render(){
return(
  <Child />
  <button onClick={() => saveColors()}>save</button>
)



class Child extends React.Component{

render(){
return(
   //those divs need to appear when we click the button with saveColors().
   <div style={{backgroundColor: color1 from Parent's state}}></div>
   <div style={{backgroundColor: color2 from Parent's state}}></div>
)
```

can i put this.state.color1 into a var and use it in the child component? or should i use return?? or something else??

Comment: Your code snippets doesn't make sense, please share proper code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to state in Parent to check button clicked. And pass value from `Parent` to `Child`:

```
this.state = {
  color1: "#38306b",
  color2: "#fff285",
  isClicked: false,
}

saveColors = () => {
  this.setState({isClicked: true})
}

<Child color1={this.state.color1} color2={this.state.color2} isClicked={this.state.isClicked} />
```

And on the `Child:

```
return (
  ...
  {this.props.isClicked && (
    <>
      <div style={{backgroundColor: this.props.color1}}></div>
      <div style={{backgroundColor: this.props.color2}}></div>
    </>
  )}
)
```

Comment: yeah but i need it to happend with the onClick function ): thats why i got lost

Comment: i think its the second time you saved me in the past week! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the state to Child as a props

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      color1: "#38306b",
      color2: "#fff285"
    }
  }

  saveColors() {
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
        <Child color={this.state} />
        <button onClick={() => this.saveColors()}>save</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: this.props.color.color1,
          height: 400
        }}>
          DIV1
        </div>
        <div style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: this.props.color.color2,
          height: 400
        }}>
          DIV2
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

And if you want to change the color when the button clicked just change the state using setState

```
  saveColors() {
    this.setState({
      color1: 'blue',
      color2: 'red'
    })
  }
```